# How to Take Top 10 Distinct Rows order by Date

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dataset

I have a Datatable having records like this...

```
JID                      Date                     RecentChatString
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
abc@gmail.com         11/Nov/2013 11:53:00        Hi 
abc@gmail.com         11/Nov/2013 11:53:10        Hello 
abc@gmail.com         11/Nov/2013 11:54:00        Good Morning 
def@gmail.com         11/Nov/2013 12:03:00        Ok 
abc@gmail.com         11/Nov/2013 12:05:10        Please reply 
def@gmail.com         11/Nov/2013 12:15:00        Good after noon 
def@gmail.com         11/Nov/2013 12:15:50        Ok bye
```

I want to get Top 10 Distinct Records sorted by Date and, Means only the recent chat of each JID..

```
JID                      Date                     RecentChatString
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
abc@gmail.com         11/Nov/2013 12:05:10        Please reply
def@gmail.com         11/Nov/2013 12:15:50        Ok bye
```

Now I have a code like this. I can get the top 10 records sorted by date using this code.
But, It contains duplicate `JID's`. Please help me. (recent_index is a DataTable)

```
DataRow recent_dr = recent_index.NewRow();
recent_dr["JID"] = RosterId;
recent_dr["Date"] = DateTime.Now;
recent_dr["RecentChatString"] = _chatline;
recent_index.Rows.Add(recent_dr);

DataTable dtt = new DataTable("RecentChats");
dtt.Columns.Add("JID", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dtt.Columns.Add("Date", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));
dtt.Columns.Add("RecentChatString", Type.GetType("System.String"));

IEnumerable<DataRow> recentTen = recent_index.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(x=>x["Date"]).Take(10);
recentTen.CopyToDataTable(dtt, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);

dtt.WriteXml(s + "\\FPhoneData\\chats\\index.xml");
```

Comment: What database engine?

Comment: have you tried `.Distinct`?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud XML...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DataTable recentTen = recent_index.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Date"))
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("JID"))
    .Take(10)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: And the LINQ master comes through again. The force is strong with you.

Comment: Doesn't that just take 10 random JID's and order them? No need to order before the Take()?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Good point, edited my answer. The first approach was more efficient but yields arbitrary rows where just the order of the `JID` groups is taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
DataView view = new DataView(recent_index);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "JID", "Date" ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .Distinct on your collection use a custom class to do distinct checking

```
private class DistinctChecker: IEqualityComparer<YourRowType>
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim's solution is correct. Here is just alternative solution with declarative query:

```
var latestMessages =
    from r in recent_index.AsEnumerable()
    group r by r.Field<string>("JID") into g
    let latest = g.OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Date")).First()
    orderby latest.Field<DateTime>("Date")
    select latest;

var recent_dr = latestMessages.Take(10).CopyToDataTable();
```